# Specify header file location for a python setup.py installation

Tags: python, gcc, header-files, setup.py

Basically the title says it all. I have a non-standard path for a library's header files and need to include it in the search path of a python installation script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/path/to/desired/include/directory` and re-run the installation script.

Comment: The 

*export*

 keyword is for unix shells. For windows users, exchange 

*export*

 with 

 *set*

and you should be good to go!